# Getting Android source

Tags: android, git, android-source

I trying to get the source of android using repo and git. Everytime I do a repo sync, the terminal indicates that it is fetching projects but it will freeze at that particular line for hours. I am guessing that my network is behind a firewall. Which port should I open? or What should I do?

Comment: This question is actually about how to get access to a git repo through a corporate firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repo is a tool build to manage git repositories, and git servers listen on port 9418 (TCP) so you would need to set up your firewall to allow appropriate access to destinations on that port.

Is this a corporate network/firewall? If it's a home network then that might not be the problem, since having such a rule to block that by default seems a little strict. Might it be a proxy problem?